# Adjectives + prepositions

Tags: prepositions, adjectives

Different adjectives are followed by different prepositions.
For example:

> I'm good at running.

or

> My answer is different from yours.

Is there any rule in adding prepositions to adjectives?

Comment: Prepositions are unruly , with a lifestyle of their own. Nope, there are no rules other than to learn them the hard way.

Comment: No: you just have to familiarise yourself with which adjectives select which complements. Try the 'Net, or a good grammar book for examples.

Comment: If so, can you give me the list of prepositions followed after adjectives?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is "no", there is no certain rule of the prepositions. You need to memorize them by yourself.

## Adjective + *about*

- angry about
- anxious about
- enthusiastic about
- excited about
- furious about
- happy about
- mad about
- nervous about
- pessimistic about
- sad about
- serious about
- upset about
- worried about

## Adjective + *at*

- amazed at
- angry at
- annoyed at
- bad at
- brilliant at
- clever at
- delighted at
- disappointed at
- excellent at
- excited at
- good at
- hopeless at
- mad at
- skilled at
- successful at
- surprised at
- terrible at
- lucky at

## Adjective + *by*

- amazed by
- delighted by
- impressed by

## Adjective + *for*

- eager for
- eligible for
- famous for
- grateful for
- notorious for
- prepared for
- ready for
- responsible for
- sorry for
- thankful for

## Adjective + *from*

- different from
- free from
- safe from

## Adjective + *in*

- disappointed in
- experienced in
- interested in
- involved in
- talented in

## Adjective + *of*

- afraid of
- ashamed of
- aware of
- capable of
- envious of
- jealous of
- kind of
- proud of

## Adjective + *to*

- allergic to
- committed to
- dedicated to
- opposed to

## Adjective + *with*

- angry with
- associated with
- confronted with
- crowded with
- fed up with
- familiar with
- similar to

## Attribution

https://www.englishclub.com/vocabulary/adjective-preposition.php

Answer (score 0):

No: you just have to familiarise yourself with which adjectives select which complements. Try the 'Net, or a good grammar book for examples. As Ronald Sole says. Prepositions are unruly, with a lifestyle of their own. There are no rules other than to learn them the hard way.

Answer (score 0):

No, there are no rules. You need to learn them the hard way. You can check this [link](https://learnenglish.britishcouncil.org/grammar/beginner-to-pre-intermediate/adjectives-and-prepositions) for further information.

Comment: Apart from whatever information the link provides, your answer doesn't add anything new to the existing answers, so at this point it is a link-only answer. Can you please relay some of the information from the linked website to your answer so it adds new information?

Comment: Joachim is right, can you include more information?